# Using Unity 8 in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mir, unity8

I want to know a few things

1. Has anyone tried Unity 8 on 16.04 ? How buggy is it ?
2. What are to commands to use it on 16.04 ?
3. My PC has Virtualbox installed. Heard Mir does not support it (?) Will I have to install something else to try Unity 8 on 16.04 ?

Thanks.